# Javascript Quiz - problems reaching the next sibling through next() method on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a quiz with JavaScript where I'm trying to use the jQuery to make 1 question appear at a time. I was able to get the html to show only one question on the page, by hiding the other elements, but for some reason I can't get the next sibling to show.
The [jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/next/) says the next() method reaches for the sibling element, but I’m not sure where the problem is.

My jQuery code is.

```
  function main()
  {
    $('.slide').hide();
    $('.active-slide').show();

    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide')
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    $('.btnNext').click(function() {
      currentSlide.removeClass('active-slide');
      nextSlide.addClass('active-slide');
    })

  }
  $(document).ready(main);
```

My HTML is.

```
        <div class="slide active-slide">
          <h3>Question 1: Answer is A! </h3>
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="correct">A</input><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="incorrect">B</input><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="incorrect">C</input><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="incorrect">D</input>
          <input type="button" class="btnNext" value="Next">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <h3>Question 2: Answer is B! </h3>
          <input type="radio" name="q2" value="incorrect">A</input><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q2" value="correct">B</input><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q2" value="incorrect">C</input><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q2" value="incorrect">D</input>
          <input type="button" class="btnNext" value="Next">
        </div>
```

The console on Chrome shows no errors which makes it harder to find.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you were hoping those two variables were going to do a live update every time the class changed, you'll be disappointed. You need to fetch the current and next slides inside the `click` handler, if that's what you're after. Should work the first time though.

Comment: Move `var currentSlide = $('.active-slide')
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();` inside the handler

Comment: @squint Thank you for the comment, It doesn't work even for the first time, so maybe I'm doing something else wrong?

Comment: @ArunPJohny doesn't help at all

Comment: I hate JQuery! I will tell you a Vanilla JS solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is the result of a jQuery selector is not `live` meaning if the selector properties of an element changes the cached object will not get updated. So you need to find the active slide inside the event handler.

The second issue could be related to css, since you are using `hide()` to hide the element, it will be using an inline `display` rule, but to show the element back you are only setting the `active-slide` class which might be having a lower order rule.

```js
function main() {

  $('.btnNext').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
    currentSlide.next().addClass('active-slide');
  })

}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.slide {
  display: none;
}
.slide.active-slide {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide active-slide">
  <h3>Question 1: Answer is A! </h3>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="correct">A
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="incorrect">B
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="incorrect">C
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="incorrect">D
  <input type="button" class="btnNext" value="Next">
</div>
<div class="slide">
  <h3>Question 2: Answer is B! </h3>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="incorrect">A
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="correct">B
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="incorrect">C
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="incorrect">D
  <input type="button" class="btnNext" value="Next">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow Arun, Genius! thank you that fixed the whole problem!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you only run the jQuery `hide` and `show` functions once; changing the classes of your `div`s isn't going to run that code again.  Your jQuery needs to do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Preston159/uwrsunco/1/) JSFiddle.

This way, the shown `div` is updated each time the classes are changed.

Comment: Wow that's really great @Preston159, it makes so much sense! I come to understand a little better on how jQuery works. Thank you